# Laravel : Not able to save to a morphmany relation

Tags: polymorphism, laravel-5

I just created a new project to get started with the polymorphic relationships in laravel, but I am stuck in an error.

I have three models.

**Book**

```
    <?php

namespace App\models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Book extends Model
{
    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $table = 'books';

    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->morphMany('App\models\Comment', 'commentable');
    }
}
```

**Movie**

```
   <?php

namespace App\models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Movie extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'movies';

    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->morphMany('App\models\Comment', 'commentable');
    }
}
```

and **Comment**:

```
namespace App\models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Comment extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'comments';

    public function commentable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}
```

I am getting an error to save the data through eloquent. Here is the function which I am running:

```
$book = Book::find(2);
$c = new Comment();
$c->body = 'currently reading';
//$output = print_r($book)
Log::info($book);
$book->comments->save($c); //error 
return view('welcome');
```

But I am getting the following error :

`Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::save()`

I went through various links and all of them seem to use the `save()` function for this. Please help me figure out the error.
I understand that it might be the case that `$book->comments' returns a collection and I can't run save on it, but then what's the way out? 
I was following [this](http://www.easylaravelbook.com/blog/2015/01/21/creating-polymorphic-relations-in-laravel-5/) tutorial which is doing it the same way.

Answer (score 1):

$book is a collection just use first() and use $book->comments()->save($c).

```
$book = Book::find(2)->first();
$c = new Comment();
$c->body = 'currently reading';
$book->comments()->save($c);
```

Comment: Still the same error. I understand what you are saying and I also think that it should work, but it's showing me the error. Did you try it?